# Read correctly a text file

Tags: c, file, struct

I should read a file formatted in this way and store infos into a structure:

```
Johnny Rico A B A B C C C B B A
Ace Levy A A B A C A C A C A
Carmen Ibanez A B B B C C B B B B
Dizzy Flores B A A B C C C B B A
Zander Barcalow A B A B C C A B B A
Carl Jenkins A A A C B C A B B B
```

**EDIT**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100

typedef struct _cad
{
    char nome[36], cognome[36];
    char risultati[50];
} Cadetto;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int j = 0, count = 0, i, k;
    char riga[255];
    Cadetto cadetti[100];
    char *ptk;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: no parameter has been passed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(riga, sizeof(riga), fp) != NULL)
    {
        j = 0;

        ptk = strtok(riga, " ");
        strcpy(cadetti[count].nome, ptk);

        ptk = strtok(NULL, " ");
        strcpy(cadetti[count].cognome, ptk);

        while (ptk != NULL)
        {
            ptk = strtok(NULL, " ");
            cadetti[count].risultati[j] = *ptk;
            j++;
        }

        count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s", cadetti[i].nome, cadetti[i].cognome);

        for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
        {
            printf(" %c", cadetti[i].risultati[k]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is the program but it doesn't work again

[image]

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854488/reading-a-string-with-spaces-with-sscanf

Comment: `strcpy(cadetti[count].risultati[j], ptk);` --> `cadetti[count].risultati[j] = *ptk;` and also reset `j` by `fgets` loop.

Comment: the program works but it doesn't print the chars correctly

Comment: I don't understand why I got that weird symbol

Comment: Debugging my code I got an error when I try to strtok the last char of the first line. Debugging my code through gdb I see that the last char of the first line is A\\r\n. So I got an error

Comment: You should really use a variable other than `j` to identify how many grades the students have.  It should probably be recorded in the `Cadetti` structure since each student could have a different number of grades.

Comment: Yes. This could be a problem in case in the file there would not be the same grades but this is not the case.

Comment: You should also modify the `while (ptk != NULL) { ptk = strtok(NULL, " "); ...` code so that it tests for nullness before using `*ptk`, like this for example: `while ((ptk = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) { ...`.  This avoids dereferencing a null pointer.  And for debugging, add copious print statements so you know what is happening and what has been read at each stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100

typedef struct _cad
{
    char nome[36], cognome[36];
    char risultati[50];
    int nrisultati;
} Cadetto;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int i, k;
    int count;
    char riga[255];
    Cadetto cadetti[N];
    char *ptk;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: no parameter has been passed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (count = 0; count < N && fgets(riga, sizeof(riga), fp) != NULL; count++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        printf("Input: %s", riga);

        ptk = strtok(riga, " ");
        strcpy(cadetti[count].nome, ptk);

        ptk = strtok(NULL, " ");
        strcpy(cadetti[count].cognome, ptk);
        printf("Name: %s %s\n", cadetti[count].nome, cadetti[count].cognome);

        while ((ptk = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
        {
            cadetti[count].risultati[j] = *ptk;
            printf("Grade %d: %c\n", j, *ptk);
            j++;
        }
        cadetti[count].nrisultati = j;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s", cadetti[i].nome, cadetti[i].cognome);

        for (k = 0; k < cadetti[i].nrisultati; k++)
        {
            printf(" %c", cadetti[i].risultati[k]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The `nrisultati` member keeps track of the number of grades of each `Cadetto` separately, in case the data is inconsistent.  The main reading loop is protected against overflowing the array.  I've not protected the name reading code from accessing a null pointer with malformed data (a single word, for example).  There could be problems if the names are overlong too.

The primary change is in the grade scanning loop; the result of `strtok()` is checked before it is used.

Sample output from given data:

```
Input: Johnny Rico A B A B C C C B B A
Name: Johnny Rico
Grade 0: A
Grade 1: B
Grade 2: A
Grade 3: B
Grade 4: C
Grade 5: C
Grade 6: C
Grade 7: B
Grade 8: B
Grade 9: A
Input: Ace Levy A A B A C A C A C A
Name: Ace Levy
Grade 0: A
Grade 1: A
Grade 2: B
Grade 3: A
Grade 4: C
Grade 5: A
Grade 6: C
Grade 7: A
Grade 8: C
Grade 9: A
Input: Carmen Ibanez A B B B C C B B B B
Name: Carmen Ibanez
Grade 0: A
Grade 1: B
Grade 2: B
Grade 3: B
Grade 4: C
Grade 5: C
Grade 6: B
Grade 7: B
Grade 8: B
Grade 9: B
Input: Dizzy Flores B A A B C C C B B A
Name: Dizzy Flores
Grade 0: B
Grade 1: A
Grade 2: A
Grade 3: B
Grade 4: C
Grade 5: C
Grade 6: C
Grade 7: B
Grade 8: B
Grade 9: A
Input: Zander Barcalow A B A B C C A B B A
Name: Zander Barcalow
Grade 0: A
Grade 1: B
Grade 2: A
Grade 3: B
Grade 4: C
Grade 5: C
Grade 6: A
Grade 7: B
Grade 8: B
Grade 9: A
Input: Carl Jenkins A A A C B C A B B B
Name: Carl Jenkins
Grade 0: A
Grade 1: A
Grade 2: A
Grade 3: C
Grade 4: B
Grade 5: C
Grade 6: A
Grade 7: B
Grade 8: B
Grade 9: B
Johnny Rico A B A B C C C B B A
Ace Levy A A B A C A C A C A
Carmen Ibanez A B B B C C B B B B
Dizzy Flores B A A B C C C B B A
Zander Barcalow A B A B C C A B B A
Carl Jenkins A A A C B C A B B B
```

With the debugging prints commented out:

```
Johnny Rico A B A B C C C B B A
Ace Levy A A B A C A C A C A
Carmen Ibanez A B B B C C B B B B
Dizzy Flores B A A B C C C B B A
Zander Barcalow A B A B C C A B B A
Carl Jenkins A A A C B C A B B B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sscanf(riga, "%s %s %s", cadetti[count].nome,
                                 cadetti[count].cognome,
                                 result);
```

==>

```
char * tmp = strtok( riga, " ");
memcpy(cadetti[count].nome,tmp,strlen(tmp)+1);

tmp= strtok (NULL " ");
memcpy(cadetti[count].cognome,tmp,strlen(tmp)+1); 

tmp= strtok(NULL,'\0');
memcpy(result,tmp,strlen(tmp)+1);
```

Comment: Result will contain every char in a cell of the array or it will contain even the spaces?

Comment: that won't compile as `nome` and `cognome` are arrays, not pointers. You need an additional `strcpy()`

Comment: @lngo Leonhardt , you are right.

Comment: @Mazzy No spaces in cadetti[count].nome and cadetti[count].cognome , while spaces saved in result .

Comment: I don't like this solution because it introduces a temp array. I tought to this solution but something goes wrong.

Comment: @Mazzy Maybe you can try a use `scanf("%c",cadetti[count].risultati[j])` in a loop to get all char without spaces. just check it >=A and <=Z .

Comment: scanf get info from stdin

Comment: @Mazzy fscanf () , it is a typo .