# reading the remainder of a string with sscanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm trying to read a string which consists of a set of numbers followed by a string, wrapped with some other basic text.

In other words, the format of the line is something like this:

```
Stuff<5,10,-5,8,"Test string here.">
```

Naively, I tried:

```
sscanf(str,"Stuff<%d,%d,%d,%d,\"%s\">",&i1,&i2,&i3,&i4,str2);
```

But after some research I discovered `%s` is supposed to stop parsing when it gets to a whitespace character.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854488/reading-a-string-with-spaces-with-sscanf), but none of the answers addresses the problem I have: the string could contain any character in it, including newline characters and properly escaped quotes.   The latter is not a problem, if I can just get sscanf to put everything after the first quote in the pre-allocated buffer I provide, I can strip the end off myself.

But how do I do this?  I can't use `%[]` because it requires something in it to terminate the string, and the only thing I want to terminate it is the null terminator.  So I thought, "Hey, I'll just use the null terminator!"  But `%[\0]` made the compiler grumpy:

```
warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format
warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format
warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format
warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format
```

Using something like `%*c` won't work either, because I don't know exactly how many characters need to be taken.  I tried passing `strlen(str)` since it will be less than that, but `sscanf` returns 4 and nothing is put into `str2`, suggesting that perhaps because the length was too long it gave up and didn't bother.

Update: I guess I could do something like:

```
sscanf(str,"Stuff<%d,%d,%d,%d,\"%n",&i1,&i2,&i3,&i4,&n);
str2 = str+n;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update seems to be a good answer.  I was going to suggest `strchr` to find the location of the first quote char, after using `sscanf` to get `i1` thru `i4`.  Side note, you should always check the return value from `sscanf` to make sure that the conversions worked. This is even more important with your suggested answer, since `n` will be left uninitialized if the first four conversions aren't successful.

Answer (score 1):

Scan for `'\"'`, then for everything not `'\"'`, then `'\"'` again.

Be sure to check `sscanf()` result and limit how long the test string may be.

```
char test_string[100];
int n = 0;
if (sscanf(str, "Stuff<%d,%d,%d,%d, \"%99[^\"]\"> %n",
      &i1, &i2, &i3, &i4, test_string, &n) == 5 && str[n] == '\0') Good();
```

---

Your attempt using `"...%[\0]..."`, from `sscanf()` point-of-view, is `"...%["`.
Everything in the format from `"\0"` on is ignored.

Using the `int n = 0`, appending `" %n"` to the format string, appending `&n` to the parameters and checking `str[n] == '\0'` is a neat trick with `sscanf()` to insure the entire line parsed correctly.  Note: `"%n"` does not add to `sscanf()` result.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the only way to achieve what you want to achieve, but probably the neatest way to do it: You'll need to use the *scansets*. I won't tell you the solution directly with this answer, I'll explain how to use scansets as far as I know them, and you'll hopefully be able to do it yourself.

Scansets `%[...]` are like `%s` when it comes to assignment, they interpret values as characters and store them into character arrays. `%s` is whitespace-terminated, `%[...]` is the flexible version of that.

There are two ways of using the scanset, first one being without a preceding caret `^`, second one being with a preceding caret `^`.

When you use scanset without the preceding caret `^`, the characters you put inside the brackets will be the only ones that will be read, stored and then left behind. As soon as `scanf` encounters a non-matching character, that `%[...]` will be over. For example:

```
// input: asdasdasdwasdasd
char s[100] = { 0 };
scanf( "%[das]", s );
printf( "%s", s );
// output: asdasdasd
```

When you use scanset with the preceding caret `^`, the search is inversed. It reads, stores and leaves behind every character until it reaches any one of the characters that you've put down after the preceding caret `^`. Example:

```
// input: abcdefgh^kekQ
char s[100] = { 0 };
scanf( "%[^Q^]", s );
printf( "%s", s );
// output: abcdefgh
```

Beware, remaining characters is still to be read inside the stream, the file pointer won't get beyond the character which caused termination. I.e. for the first one, `getchar( );` would give a `'w'`, and for the second one it would give a `'^'`.

I hope this will be enough. If you still cannot find your way out, ask away, I can give you a solution.