# c: how to use strtok() for double brackets?

Tags: c

I'd like to know how to use `strtok` to find values between double brackets,
so is that possible to use `strtok(mystr, "[]")` or no?
thanks.

Comment: Find the first bracket `strtok(data, "[")` then the second `strtok(NULL, "]")`; but you really shouldn't be using `strtok()` for parsing a string.

Comment: I like to do it with strtok

Comment: @user3464495: depending on the application you can walk the string char-by-char until you find what you want and copy that to another string. Or use `strchr()` to find the interesting markers directly, or try regular expressions

Comment: I don't think anyone *likes* parsing with `strtok`.  Well, maybe masochists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `strtok` as described in the following example:

```
int main ()
{
    char str[] ="[x][y] [z]"; // sample string

    // make a copy of the original string to work on
    char *wrk;
    wrk = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    strcpy(wrk, str);

    // we need a copy of the pointer wrk
    // to be used as parameter for strtok
    char *wrk2;
    wrk2 = wrk;

    // this will hold the pointer to the string returned from strtok
    char * pch;

    while(true)
    {
        pch = strtok(wrk2, "[]");
        if( !pch ) break;
        wrk2 = NULL; // subsequent calls to strtok require wrk2 to be NULL

        // the value is good only if preceeded by an open bracket
        // because strtok retrieve also strings between ] and [
        if(pch>wrk && str[pch-wrk-1]=='[')
        {
            printf ("%s\n",pch);
        }
    }

    free(wrk);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that in order to use `strtok` to accomplish what you asked a copy of the original string have to be generated. Let's call it the *working string* `wrk`

`strtok(wrk, "[]")` will retrieve both **good** substrings between `[`  `]` and **unwanted** substrings between `]`  `[`.

In order to skip unwanted strings a check is made to see if the returned substring is preceeded by an open bracket `[`.

The necessity of checking this is the reason why a copy of the original string has to be made: in fact `strtok` edits (splits) the *working string* by placing null termination characters. The check is made on the original untouched string.

Using `strtok` results to be quite complicated and require (at least with the approach I suggested) a copy of the original string.

Also the above code won't handle nested string, for example `[[a] b]`

For complete reference about `strtok` I suggest http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: This version fails on "[x] [y] [z]". It fails to show "x".

Comment: @mbratch: you're right again, thank you. I edited the answer. However now a different approach is taken and copy of the original string is needed.

Comment: I believe that finally nails it, except for the nested brackets, as you point out. The lesson is that it isn't as straight-forward solving this problem with `strtok` as one might initially think. :)

Comment: @mbratch: I agree, it's not straight-forward at all. And the code is quite ugly too. I would never follow that approach in a program of mine. But that's what the OP asked for... :)

Answer (score 3):

As per your comment, asking about what else you should be using, my offer would be to use `scanf` with scansets `%[...]`, in the following way:

```
char inside[100];
if ( scanf( "%*[^[][%99[^]]", inside ) == 1 ) {
    ...
}
```

I know, it could possibly look all gibberish as it is if you are not familiar with scansets, so let me explain it briefly:

Scanset `%[...]` is just another type of type-specifier, like `"%s"` and `"%d"` and so on. It is really similar to `"%s"`, except that it is flexible. By specifying characters inside `[...]`, that doesn't start with a caret `^`, those characters will be the only ones that'll be read. In other words, anything else than the specified terminates reading.

When you start off with a caret `^` effect is inversed, the first encounter of the specified characters terminates the scanset reading.

An asterisk `*` right after the percent sign `%`, means "Hey, I want you to find these values, but I don't want you to store them into anything, I want them to be discarded."

So, the format string above tells the `scanf` to;

- read and discard until the first `'['`, with the `"%*[^[]` part
- read and discard the `'['` character afterwards with the `"["` part
- read and store the string until the next `']'` character, with maximum length 99 (taking terminating null into consideration), with the `"%99[^]]"` part

For scanset examples, you may check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22722090/2736228