# Using sscanf to read strings with white spaces in C

Tags: c

I am trying to get use sscanf to scan a string of text and store the values into an array. When it comes to storing the last string it stops scanning when it comes to a white space. For example in the below string it would only store the word "STRING". I have tried using %[^ \t\n] and the other various specifiers but it seems I am missing something.

I just cant get the function to include white space, im sure its probably something simple.

```
string test = "9999:STRING OF TEXT";

scan = sscanf(test, "%d:%s", rec[i].ref, rec[i].string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this does not work?

```
sscanf(test, "%d:%[^\t\n]", rec[i].ref, rec[i].string);
```

check out this answer : [reading a string with spaces with sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854488/reading-a-string-with-spaces-with-sscanf)

Basically this will will match the number, followed by anything that is not in the brackets (tab, newline), note the ^ symbol.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression the it should read "%d:%s[^\t\n]" knew it would be something stupid on my end!

Answer (score 2):

You should have posted a minimal working code.

However, the issue is most likely that %s does not skip white space as do the numerical formats such as %f and %d. Use something like `sscanf(test, "%d:%[^\n]", rec[i].ref, rec[i].string);` to capture whatever is after `:`.

Look here for details: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/][1]

Comment: `%s` does skip initial white space.