# Reading a string with spaces and special character with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

For a project I'm trying to read an int and a string from a string. Here the only problem is sscanf appears to break reading an `%s` when it sees a space and some special character. I want to print only String which is present inside special character. Is there anyway to get around this limitation? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

Similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854488/reading-a-string-with-spaces-with-sscanf) with little change

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int age;
    char* buffer;
    buffer = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
    sscanf("19 cool kid >>> ram <<<", "%d %[^\t\n] >>> %*s <<<", &age, buffer);

    printf("%s is %d years old\n", buffer, age);
    return 0;
}
```

What it prints is: **"cool kid >>> ram <<< is 19 years old"** where I need **"ram is 19 years old"**. Is there any work around?

**Note: some time "cool kid" string come "coolkid" like this also.**

Comment: Well, you could try taking the '19' and two instances of `>>>` and `<<<` out of the quoted string you're passing to `sscanf` to start. If you put them into the string, they're going to be there when you print it back out.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `sscanf()`? a bit extra effort with `strtok()` will give you lot more flexibility, IMHO.

Comment: when calling malloc() 1) the expression: 'sizeof(char)' is defined as 1 and has no effect on the value passed to malloc..   to declutter the code remove that useless expression.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this: '%[^\t\n]' is incorrect as there is no tab and no newline in the source string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for things that aren't a `>`, and you need to suppress assignment on the correct bits:

```
sscanf("19 cool kid >>> ram <<<", "%d %*[^>] >>> %199s <<<", &age, buffer);
```

The length quoted in the format is one less than the number of characters available; it doesn't count the terminal null byte, in other words.

Comment: The original input had a single sequence of `>>>` characters before the bit you're interested in. The 'scan set' `%*[^>]` contains an 'assignment suppression' `*`, and then a negated (`^`) set of characters, `>`. This looks for one or more characters that is not a `>`.  In context, that's after the `19`, so it matches the string `" cool kid "`. If you need to match the word `ram` in `"19 cool kid >>> >>> ram <<<"`, then you need to think much harder.  What other variations in the input are possible? How do you spot the part that's to be matched? Is `"19 cool >>> ewe >>> ram <<<"` valid?  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

You had it, you just had your discard in the wrong place (along with a slight capitalization issue):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    int age;
    char* buffer;
    if (!(buffer = malloc(200 * sizeof *buffer))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    sscanf("19 cool kid >>> ram <<<", "%d %*[^>] >>> %s <<<", &age, buffer);

    printf("%s is %d years old\n", buffer, age);

    free (buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/sscanf_strange
ram is 19 years old
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use `sscanf(input, "%d%*[^>]>>>%199s", &age, buffer);`.  Anything after the `%s` is irrelevant in scanning for `age` and `buffer`.  Not checking if all scanned can lead to trouble.

Suggest checking that the entire line parsed as expected.  The simple solution is to use `" %n"` at the end.  This saves the count of `char` scanned if scanning gets that far.

```
const char *input =  "19 cool kid >>> ram <<<";
int n = 0;
sscanf(input, "%d%[^>]>>>%*199s <<< %n", &age, buffer, &n);
if (n == 0 || input[n]) {
  puts("Bad Input");
}
```